# Multiple conditional emails sent based on Google Form submission

Tags: email, google-apps-script, conditional-statements, switch-statement, google-forms

I use the below script with a google form which sends an email to different people based on the answer chosen on the form.  The script works and sends an email to the correct person when I use it with a form where the user can only choose one option.

But now I have a form where a user can choose between 1 and 6 options for the selection of cases to match.  For every option chosen, I need an email to be sent to the corresponding department.  With switch command, I understand that it tests an expression against a list of cases and returns the corresponding value of the *first* matching case.  What I need is for it to test against a list of cases and return *ALL* corresponding values and then email based on that. Sometimes that would be one email, sometimes that could be 3 emails to 3 different people, etc.

The question on the google form is a checkbox question so a user can choose any and all if it applies.  Each option correlates with a different email in my script.

[image: image of question]

Currently, if the form is filled out and only one option is chosen (see screenshot question "announcement outlet"), the script runs and sends the email as it should.  But if two or more options are selected, no email goes out.  When I check the trigger notes, the error is:

> Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient
> at sendFormByEmail(Code:47:13)

Here is my current script which works when only one option can be chosen.  I believe I need a different command other than switch, but don't know what. I looked into fallthrough, but don't think that would work for this either.

```js
function sendFormByEmail(e)
{      
  // Remember to replace XYZ with your own email address  
  var named_values = e.namedValues  
  var teachername = named_values["Teacher Name"];    
  var info = named_values["Your message/announcement"];  
  var time = named_values["Please include time frame"];  
  var photos = named_values["Include photos with this form if applicable; you can also create the graphic for social media and include below"];  
  var announce = named_values["Choose announcement outlet"].toString();  
  var email;
 
 // Optional but change the following variable  
// to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails  
  
// The variable e holds all the form values in an array.  
// Loop through the array and append values to the body.  
var message = "";      
for(var field in e.namedValues) {    
  message += field + ' :: ' 
                + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n"; 
   }   

  switch (announce) {    
  case "School Intercom Announcement":      
    var email = "person1@school.net";      
    break;    
  case "MHHS Website":      
    var email = "person2@school.net";      
    break;    
  case "MHHS Social Media (Instagram, Facebook, Twitter)":      
    var email = "person3@school.net"     
    break;    
  case "Week in Pics":      
    var email = "person4@school.net"  
    var body = "Week in Pics Request"    
    break;  
  case "Remind text message (goes to students - please specify in your message info if it is all grades or specific grades)":
    var email = "person5@school.net"
    var subject = "Remind Text Request"
    break;
  case "Phone call home":
    var email = "person6@school.net"
    break;
  }  
     // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script  
    // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp here.  
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);   
    }
```

When multiple options are chosen, the data in the cell reads "Option 2, Option 4" and all my listed cases in the script above are for only "Option 2" or "Option 4", etc.  Is there a way make this happen without having to make a case for every possible combination of the 6 choices that could potentially happen?

Comment: Please be more specific about how the script breaks. If you are getting an error message, add it textually into the question body. The form can't be viewed, anyway, questions should be self-contained so please describe the relevant parts of the form, i.e. what question is the the one that allow selecting multiple choices.

Comment: Please provide an image of your linked sheet

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Rubén I've added more specifics to my issue in the hopes you can help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you reply Jenny. While links to external content might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Considering this, please add all the relevant details directly into the question body, in this specific case a screenshot of the form might work. Regarding the spreadsheet, insert some sample data as text (you could use markdown to format it as a table).

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix the code

1. Remove `.toString()` from `var announce = named_values["Choose announcement outlet"].toString();`. Rationale: There is no need to convert an Array into a string for this case.
2. Instead of  `switch` use `if`'s, more specifically, add one `if` for each `case` clause, using an expression to test if the `case` label is included in `announce`. Example:

   Replace

   ```
   case "School Intercom Announcement":
   ```

   by

   ```
   if(announce.includes("School Intercom Announcement")){
      // put here the case clause, don't include break;

      // Add the following line before the closing `}` of the if statement 
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
   }
   ```

   Rationale: It's easier to implement the required control logic using `if` and `Array.prototype.includes` rather than doing it using `switch`.

Comment: I'm getting a Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' line: 24 file: Code.gs  (this is at the end of the if statement).  I've tried a couple different variations with no luck.

Comment: There was a missing closing parenthesis in the code in my answer. Fixed now. This is something that any Google Apps Script user should be able figured out by themselves. Please consider to spend some time learning the pretty basics of JavaScript and to learn how to find / fix syntax errors in Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you Ruben- yes, I can't even be called a novice, I'm just trying to create some automated forms for our small rural public school.  I appreciate your help.  Syntax error now gone but this seems to do the same thing my original script did - it sends the email if one option is chosen, but if more than one option chosen, I get the same error "Failed to Send Email: no recipient"

Comment: I think that simple fix is to add `MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); ` at the end each if statement block. (before the closing `}`). P.S. I suggest you to learn to use `console.log` to print variable values in the execution logs to help you understand what is happening with the on form submit trigger. Later you might learn about how to test this kind of functions from the Google Apps Script editor.

Comment: Ok, tried that.  Still works when choosing one option only.  Does not work with multi-options chosen.  Strangely, it's not throwing any errors.  The executions log says the trigger completed successfully and I have no failure summaries, but no email was sent from the account.

Comment: I think that the best is that you post a new question including the new code and some sample form submission data as text.