# Simultaneous emails sent to different addresses based on form input

Tags: if-statement, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

What I have:

- A google form with checkbox options so the user can choose ALL that
  apply (6 total options)
- For each option, there is a specific email associated with each option (6 different emails)

What is occurring:

- When a single option is chosen, the email goes out to the correct person
- When multiple options are chosen, an email goes out only to the first option
- The spreadsheet collects the data correctly, showing all the options chosen, but only one email actually goes out

What I need:

- Multiple emails sent to the different specified addresses if their option is one of the selected ones

Current Script:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e)
{ 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e))     
  // Remember to replace XYZ with your own email address  
  var named_values = e.namedValues  
  var teachername = named_values["Teacher Name"];    
  var info = named_values["Your message/announcement"];  
  var time = named_values["Please include time frame"];  
  var photos = named_values["Include photos with this form if applicable; you can also create the graphic for social media and include below"];  
  var announce = e.values[3];
  var address = [];
     
  if(announce.match('School Intercom Announcement')){
    var address = "mhhsmedia@yanceync.net";
    var subject = "School Announcement Request";
   }

  if(announce.match('MHHS Website')){     
    var address = "heritagecougars@yanceync.net";
    var subject = "Website posting request";    
  } 
    
  if(announce.match('MHHS Social Media')) {    
    var address = "socialmedia@yanceync.net";
    var subject = "Social Media Request"; 
   }

  if(announce.match('Week in Pics')) {    
    var address = "ycspics@yanceync.net";  
    var subject= "Week in Pics Request";
   }

  if(announce.match('Remind text message')){
    var address = "jstipton@yanceync.net";
    var subject = "Remind message request";
   }

  if(announce.match('Phone call home')){
    var address = "blackboardcall@yanceync.net";
    var subject = "All-Call Request"; 
  }


  
// The variable e holds all the form values in an array.  
// Loop through the array and append values to the body.  ;
var email = address
var message = "";      
for(var field in e.namedValues)    
  message += field + ' :: ' 
                + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n"; 
   MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

    }
```

Things I have tried with no luck:

I attempted to join the addresses with:

```
 var email = address.join(",")
```

This gave me a script failure that `address.join` was not a function

I tried including under each `if` statement:

```
 var email = "jstipton@yanceync.net";
    var subject = "All-Call Request";      
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
```

This resulted in still only one email being sent to the first option chosen, regardless of how many were chosen after it.

Thank you in advance for your willingness to assist me!

Answer (score 1):

If you have included,under each if statement, the`MailApp.sendEmail` code and only 1 email is send, that's because your are entering in only one condition.

But why `announce` match only 1 condition ? I believe there is only one value `announce='Week in Pics'` (or equivalent) passed into the `sendFormByEmail(e)` function.
So be sure that `announce` have a value like `"School Intercom Announcement MHHS Website "`

Just for you information, there is a lot to say about your code :

The way value is affected into address field  (several `var address`) is not so good. You used array, that's a perfect start, but to add data into an array, it's the **push** method :

```
//  what you use
var address = [];  // address = [] an array
var address = "mhhsmedia@yanceync.net"; // address = "mhhsmedia@yanceync.net" a string
var address = "heritagecougars@yanceync.net"; // address = "heritagecougars@yanceync.net" a string

//  what work 
var address = []; // address = [] an array
address.push("mhhsmedia@yanceync.net"); // address = ["mhhsmedia@yanceync.net"] an array of string
address.push("heritagecougars@yanceync.net"); // address = ["mhhsmedia@yanceync.net","heritagecougars@yanceync.net"] an array of string

// So your code can look like as bellow
// ...
var address = [];

  if(announce.match('School Intercom Announcement')){
    address.push("mhhsmedia@yanceync.net");
    subject.push("School Announcement Request");
   }

  if(announce.match('MHHS Website')){     
    address.push("heritagecougars@yanceync.net");
    subject.push("Website posting request"); 
  } 
// ...
for (var email in address){
  var subjectToSend = subject.pop()
  //...
}
```

As improvement, you can use switch [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement, that is far more easier to read than several if.

Finally, match is for [regex](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/understanding-regex), if you never heard of such thing have a look, it's a life changer.

Comment: I had switch at first (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964321/multiple-conditional-emails-sent-based-on-google-form-submission) but couldn't get that to work either.  I've updated my code based on your recommendation- I'm getting an error "subject not defined" - thank you for your help.  As you can tell, I cannot even be called a novice and just trying to get something to work for my school.

Comment: No wories, everybody were a novice once. I'm sure we can do what you are looking for. But we need your help : a data sample (in a way we can take it and reproduce exactly) + what it should happend. Make sure to read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the way how sendFormByEmail(e) is call ? Using trigger ? Attach script to a button ?

Comment: It is a trigger on form submit.  I'm working on how to submit a data sample